# "What it makes sense for people to accept?"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Although these writers all deploy much of the social contract idiom, then, at the end of the day their arguments rest on accounts  of  **what  it  makes  sense  for  people  to  accept**,  not  what anyone accepts in fact.
>
> Moral Foundation of Politics by Ian Shapiro

I don't understand what author wants to mean by saying "what  it  makes  sense  for  people  to  accept".
I think this means : Their arguments rest on accounts of the sense that acceptance make for people.
Am I right of not?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct, if confusingly worded.

In this sentence, "what it makes sense for people to accept" modifies "accounts". The accounts are stories of things that people accepted, so they are things "it makes sense for people to accept".